# Blogger Drop Down Menus

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am no CSS/HTML coder but I do know how to read code and can get by when I have to.  I have a Blogger site and I want drop down menus to match my website.  I have Googled this and tried examples till I'm blue in the face without success.  It shouldn't be that hard.  Anyway, I shamelessly "borrowed" the CSS code from this post [Blogger drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181931/blogger-drop-down-menu) and coupled it with the HTML/Javascript Widget code below.  But my 3 level menu shows up as 3 rows which I obviously don't want.  This may be beyond the scope of this group but I thought I'd try anyway.  I really want this to work.

Am I in the right place for help?  If there is a simpler solution to a Drop Down Menu for Blogger, I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks!!

My blog:  [My blog](http://adahighlanderphotography.blogspot.com)

Here is the CSS and HTML/Javascript code:

```css
/*----- MBT Drop Down Menu ----*/
#mbtnavbar {
    /* background: #a3a3a3; */
    width: 960px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-top:0px solid #000000;
    height: 5px;
}
#mbtnavbar {
    borderleft:0px solid #000000;
    border-right:0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:0px solid #000000;
}
#mbtnav {
    background:#ededed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav ul {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position:relative;
    /* border-left:1px solid #333; border-right:1px solid #333; */
    height:40px;
}
#mbtnav li a, #mbtnav li a:link, #mbtnav li a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font:bold 22px Times new roman, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mbtnav li a:hover, #mbtnav li a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
}
#mbtnav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}
#mbtnav li ul {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height:160px;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
}
#mbtnav li ul a {
    width: 180px;
}
#mbtnav li ul ul {
    margin: -25px 0 0 161px;
}
#mbtnav li:hover ul ul, #mbtnav li:hover ul ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}
#mbtnav li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: 0px;
}
#mbtnav li:hover, #mbtnav li.sfhover {
    position: relative;
}
#mbtnav li li a, #mbtnav li li a:link, #mbtnav li li a:visited {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    /* width: 100px; */
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font:bold 14px Times new roman, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index:9999;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}
#mbtnav li li a:hover, #mbtnavli li a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #000000;
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.tabs-inner .widget #mbtnavbar li a {
    border-left:none;
}
.tabs-outer .widget, .section {
    margin:0;
}
.tabs-inner {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!--Start Navigation --> 
<div id=’mbtnavbar’>
   <ul id=’mbtnav’>
      <li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com">HOME</a></li> 
      <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a ref='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes'>
                  LANDSCAPES</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>WILDLIFE/NATURE</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Birds/'>
                        BIRDS</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Butterflies/'>
                        BUTTERFLIES</a></li>
                  <li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Flowers/'>
                        FLOWERS</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/2017-Photo-of-the-Week/'>PHOTO OF THE WEEK</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes-1/2017-Michigan-Calendar-Photos/'>2017 CALENDAR PHOTOS</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Notecards'> NOTECARDS</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Contact">CONTACT ME</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://blog.adahighlanderphotography.com">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/About-Me2">ABOUT ME</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>   
<!--End Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple drop down menu like this:

```css
    /*----- MBT Drop Down Menu ----*/
#mbtnavbar {
    /* background: #a3a3a3; */
    width: 960px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-top:0px solid #000000;
    height: 5px;
}
#mbtnavbar {
    borderleft:0px solid #000000;
    border-right:0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:0px solid #000000;
}
#mbtnav {
    background:#ededed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav ul {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mbtnav li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position:relative;
    /* border-left:1px solid #333; border-right:1px solid #333; */
    height:40px;
}
#mbtnav li a, #mbtnav li a:link, #mbtnav li a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font:bold 22px Times new roman, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mbtnav li a:hover, #mbtnav li a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
}
#mbtnav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}
#mbtnav li ul {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height:195px;
    width: 205px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
}
#mbtnav li ul a {
    width: 180px;
}
#mbtnav li ul ul {
    margin: -25px 0 0 161px;
}
#mbtnav li:hover ul ul, #mbtnav li:hover ul ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}
#mbtnav li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: 0px;
}
#mbtnav li:hover, #mbtnav li.sfhover {
    position: relative;
}
#mbtnav li li a, #mbtnav li li a:link, #mbtnav li li a:visited {
    
    /* width: 100px; */
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font:bold 14px Times new roman, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index:9999;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}
#mbtnav li li a:hover, #mbtnavli li a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #000000;
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.tabs-inner .widget #mbtnavbar li a {
    border-left:none;
}
.tabs-outer .widget, .section {
    margin:0;
}
.tabs-inner {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!--Start Navigation --> 
<div id='mbtnavbar'>
<ul id='mbtnav'>

<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com">HOME</a></li> 
<li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a>
<ul>
<li><a ref='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes'>
LANDSCAPES</a></li>
<li><a href=''>WILDLIFE/NATURE</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Birds/'>
BIRDS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Butterflies/'>
BUTTERFLIES</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/WildlifeFlowers-1/Flowers/'>
FLOWERS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/2017-Photo-of-the-Week/'>PHOTO OF THE WEEK</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Landscapes-1/2017-Michigan-Calendar-Photos/'>2017 CALENDAR PHOTOS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Products/Notecards'>
NOTECARDS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/Contact">CONTACT ME</a></li>
<li><a href="http://blog.adahighlanderphotography.com">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.adahighlanderphotography.com/About-Me2">ABOUT ME</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I see yours works in the code snippet window.  I've compared yours line by line to mine. I see no differences in the HTML code. And only 3 minor differences in the CSS code.  Can you help me understand why yours works and mine doesn't?  I still have to try adding it to my blog but at least yours works here.

Comment: I just plugged your code into my blogger page and the top level menu looks fine.  But the Portfolio menu does not drop down when hovered over.  Ideas?

Comment: OK so this just gets more confusing to me by the minute.  If I copy and paste your HTML code into my HTML/Javascript widget, I at least get the top level menu looking correct albeit the drop downs don't work.  If I paste the EXACT same code from a file I have on my Mac into the same widget, I get the 3 rows of menu, submenu, and subsubmenu again.  What the?

Comment: So I've been going through this now line by line and I understand a lot more of it.  I've discovered that my drop down menus are being hidden by the current blog post.  I have a screen shot showing it but I can't see how I can attach it to show you.  The z-index property is set to 9999 which indicates to me it was trying to assure it was on top of anything else on the screen but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Can you please share me your link or screenshot of your dropdownmenu?

Comment: Let's close this.  I'm going to start a new thread with a different example that is 98% of what I want.